# GraphQL "$id" of required type "Int!" was not provided

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have some issues with my code, I'm working with Gatsby and Gatsby Awesome Pagination,

So I don't know what is going on, because on **gatsby develop** is working but when I use

**gatsby build** it says

*There was an error in your GraphQL query:
Variable "$id" of required type "Int!" was not provided.*

This is my code in gatsby-node.js

```
  const BlogPosts = result.data.allWordpressPost.edges
  paginate({
    createPage, 
    items: BlogPosts, 
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    itemsPerFirstPage: 10,
    pathPrefix: '/blog',
    component: path.resolve('./src/pages/blog.js'), 
  })
  BlogPosts.forEach(post => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${post.node.slug}`,
      component: BlogSinglePage,
      context: {
        id: post.node.wordpress_id,
      },
    })

  })
```

And this is my code in Blog.js

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allWordpressPost(
      skip: $skip 
      limit: $limit 
    ) 
    {
      edges {
        node {
          wordpress_id
          title
          excerpt
          slug
          date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
          categories {
            name
            slug
          }
          featured_media {
            source_url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't your "Blog.js" in "src/pages"?

as Gatsby core automatically turns react components in "src/pages" into pages with urls, I recommend that you move your "Blog.js" to "src/templates"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the build works fine but I'm getting a warning "Exported queries are only executed for page components." Any solution for that @sijin

Answer (score 0):

**Two Simple steps:**

1: Move your Blog.js into 'src/templates.

2: Modify 'gatsby-node.js'

```
component: path.resolve('./src/templates/Blog.js'),
```